# R : Roll up by each variable and taking total count

Tags: r

I have a data set something similar to this with around 80 variables (flags) and 80,000 rows

```
< Acc_Nbr flag1 flag2 flag3 flag4 Exposure
<  ab       1     0    1     0        1000
<  bc       0     1    1     0        2000
<  cd       1     1    0     1        3000
<  ef       1     0    1     1        4000
<  Expected Output
< Variable  Count_Acct_Number Sum_Exposure Total_Acct_Number Total_Expo
< flag1         3                   8000        4                10000
< flag2         2                   5000        4                10000
< flag3         3                   7000        4                10000
< flag4         2                   7000        4                10000
```

Basically I want the output to show me count of account number and sum of exposure which are marked as 1 for each variable and in front of them total count of account numbers and exposures.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, reshape it to 'long' with `melt`, grouped by 'variable', we get the `sum` of 'value1', `sum` of 'Exposure' where 'value1' is 1, number of rows (`.N`), and the `sum` of all the values in 'Exposure' to get the expected output.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure=patterns("^flag"))[,
       list(Count_Acct_Number= sum(value1), 
            Sum_Exposure= sum(Exposure[value1==1]),
            Total_Acct_Number = .N,
            TotalExposure=sum(Exposure)),
        by = variable]
#    variable Count_Acct_Number Sum_Exposure Total_Acct_Number TotalExposure
#1:    flag1                 3         8000                 4         10000
#2:    flag2                 2         5000                 4         10000
#3:    flag3                 3         7000                 4         10000
#4:    flag4                 2         7000                 4         10000
```

Answer (score 0):

A straigthforward way is to use the doBy package

```
library(doBy)
df <- data.frame(account=LETTERS[1:10], exposure=1:10*3.14, mark=round(runif(10)))
res <- as.data.frame(summaryBy(exposure~mark+account, df, FUN=sum))
subset(res, mark==0)
```

Starting with the base data (note, sample has randoms in it)

```
> df
   account exposure mark
1        A     3.14    1
2        B     6.28    1
3        C     9.42    0
4        D    12.56    0
5        E    15.70    1
6        F    18.84    0
7        G    21.98    1
8        H    25.12    0
9        I    28.26    1
10       J    31.40    0
```

gives temp result which has marked the marks (in this case there is no actual summing, but would do as well)

```
> res
   mark account exposure.sum
1     0       A         3.14
2     0       D        12.56
3     0       F        18.84
4     0       H        25.12
5     1       B         6.28
6     1       C         9.42
7     1       E        15.70
8     1       G        21.98
9     1       I        28.26
10    1       J        31.40
```

The final result can be selected with

```
> subset(res, mark==0)
  mark account exposure.sum
1    0       A         3.14
2    0       D        12.56
3    0       F        18.84
4    0       H        25.12
```